# Predicate calculus statement and its negation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm working on a logic statement, and I'm supposed to give its negation. This is the logic statement I came up with:

$$∀x∈Z,ꓱ y ∈ Z,(x < 0)→ (y^2 ≥ x)$$

And its negation:

$$ꓱx∈Z,∀ y ∈ Z,(x ≥ 0)\wedge ¬(y^2 < x)$$

I'm wondering if the negation looks correct and the overall logic makes sense.

Comment: $$\text{Hint}: \neg(P\to Q)\equiv P\land\neg Q$$

Answer (score 2):

You didn't negate the innermost statement correctly.  Consider: When is $p\rightarrow q$ false?  Answer: When $p$ is true but $q$ is false.  Your negated statement should thus instead be:

$$ꓱx∈Z,∀ y ∈ Z,(x < 0)\wedge ¬(y^2 < x)$$